# Begin with AWS or Azure ML Course? (or something else?)

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I tend to see a lot of ML/AI/DL courses everywhere. Having no background in either of these, I am confused about what to do and where to begin. I was suggested to have a look into the Stanford Andrew Ng ML course. That seems pretty outdated now. I see Python libraries being used always everywhere.

The following two courses came to my notice :

1. [ML with Azure](https://www.udacity.com/scholarships/machine-learning-scholarship-microsoft-azure)
2. [AWS ML Program](https://www.udacity.com/scholarships/aws-machine-learning-scholarship-program)

Apart from that, there are several Andrew Ng/Coursera courses available on the internet. I would be equally happy to check out books instead of/alongside (an) online course(s). Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing the Andrew Ng course and I'm enjoying it even if it's old. There's a lot of concepts in it that are still used today.

Although he uses Octave/ Matlab instead of Python I would still recommend this course not only because it's basically recommended all over the internet but this guy knows his stuff. There's a free **18 hour** video playlist on Youtube that you can check if you feel like not paying for the **54 hour** one on Coursera. It covers just as many topics.

As for books I would recommend **An Introduction to Statistical Learning** if you're just starting out and **Elements of Statistical Learning** if you're a bit more advanced.

Again this is from personal experience.